# Detect websites that try to install programs

Tags: security

I am new to `PHP` and trying to learn if there is a way to catch websites that install programs in to your computer without your authorization. For example, when you visit some websites, your computer might catch a virus just by going to that web page. Just by looking at its `html` code, is there a way I can see if a webpage is trying to install something in to my computer? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: A `firewall` will normally do this. `PHP`, no.

Comment: That has nothing to do with PHP (on your side at least)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments and answers. that helped me clear things out. I really appriciate all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To run code without your consent (or install malicious software) in context of the whole system (not just web application / browser), coders use known or unknown bugs in browsers. Example of Javascript exploit: [Help me understand this JavaScript exploit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381171/help-me-understand-this-javascript-exploit). My antivirus tries not to let me on that page ;)

To check with php if given page contains malicious code, you'd need to use php-based antivirus or one that has php bindings / lets scan files on demand from command line and works against web-based (html,css,js-based) malware.

Answer (score 1):

You are fundamentally mistaking about the concept of "infecting a computer" via a website.
Usually an attacker would use an exploit to target certain browsers, this will load a "payload" and from there the computer is powned. This "expoit" could be anything from crafted JavaScript to malicious flash files. This is a direct manner of infecting a computer, note that this is not effective unless you don't have an antivirus, up to date browser/software or the attacker is using a [0-day exploit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-day_attack).

The effective way an attacker could infect his visitors is by letting them download something and infecting them directly. Note that a website *can't* just install something on your computer unless the user downloads it and manually installs it.

It sounds like an anti-virus program is the solution, but how do they detect malicious code ?
One of the techniques they use is scanning for certain "signs" of a program/code. The AV has a database of those signs, and scans against it.

To answer your question, it may be possible to do it with PHP **but** it's like using a fork to dig a cave. Note that you will need to develop a method to detect malicious code, this can be done by comparing hex codes(signs), you'll need a full database of it. And the most fun part is, the attacker could just change slightly his code and your scanner will fail. Also obfuscated code will let your scanner fail.

That's why one should never even think about building a virus scanner with PHP. Use an antivirus. They are smarter, faster and the people working behind it are hackers. Just one technique of my head they use [heuristic analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heuristic_analysis).

Answer (score 0):

Not really, antivirus, antispyware and that sort of software does that for you.